# How can I let html table borders merge into each other in css

Tags: html, css, html-table

In a current project I have a three-columned table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Entschuldigt?</th>
        <th>Vermerkt von</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My current stylesheet for the table looks as following:

```
th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td + td {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Now the table looks like this [image: current_table]

Now I would like to have those little spaces removed so the column separators and the header separator are solid and not that kind of dashed. Every help is very much appreciated

Comment: please make sure to upvote my post if you think it can be helpful for other people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `border-collapse: collapse` on the table:

```css
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td+td {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Entschuldigt?</th>
    <th>Vermerkt von</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  In js-fiddle that left me with a right border that might be desired I got rid of the right rule and also centered it, looks all right.

Comment: Also check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: I will try this out as soon as possible and then give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

## Another Approach:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: Anytime with pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}  
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: none;
}

tr:nth-child(2){
   border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Entschuldigt?</th>
    <th>Vermerkt von</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```